# Power simulations for mixed models with factors

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to calculate power for fixed effects in a mixed model where two variables are coded as factors (to test for linear or quadratic effects). But when I run powerSim, the results show 0% even though the effect is significant.

This is not the case when I run powerSim for model building on "raw" variables.

```
> freq <- as.factor(b1$f)
> loc <-as.factor(b1$l)
> cp <- contr.poly 
> m2<-lmer(scr~ freq+loc+freq:loc+(1|id), data=b1, contrasts=list(freq=cp))
> summary(m2)
```

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: scr ~ freq + loc + freq:loc + (1 | id)
   Data: b1

REML criterion at convergence: 3672.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3274 -0.4298 -0.0761  0.2343  6.0536 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.00242  0.04919 
 Residual             0.19264  0.43891 
Number of obs: 3008, groups:  id, 44

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -8.180e-03  1.093e-02  4.073e+01  -0.748   0.4585    
freq.L       8.393e-02  1.962e-02  2.951e+03   4.277 1.95e-05 ***
freq.Q       1.789e-02  1.961e-02  2.952e+03   0.912   0.3617    
freq.C      -1.788e-03  1.961e-02  2.952e+03  -0.091   0.9273    
freq^4      -1.207e-02  1.960e-02  2.951e+03  -0.616   0.5381    
freq^5      -4.180e-02  1.959e-02  2.951e+03  -2.134   0.0329 *  
loc1         2.257e-03  8.003e-03  2.952e+03   0.282   0.7779    
freq.L:loc1 -3.800e-02  1.962e-02  2.952e+03  -1.937   0.0529 .  
freq.Q:loc1  3.671e-02  1.961e-02  2.951e+03   1.872   0.0613 .  
freq.C:loc1 -6.637e-03  1.961e-02  2.951e+03  -0.339   0.7350    
freq^4:loc1  3.510e-02  1.960e-02  2.952e+03   1.791   0.0734 .  
freq^5:loc1 -2.724e-02  1.959e-02  2.952e+03  -1.391   0.1644    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
> powerSim(m2,test=fixed("freq"), nsim=100)
```

```
Power for predictor 'freq', (95% confidence interval):==============================================|
       0.00% ( 0.00,  3.62)

Test: unknown test

Based on 100 simulations, (0 warnings, 100 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = NA

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 1 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

Is it possible to simulate power for the factorial design of a mixed model?

Comment: When using a non-base package like [simr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/simr/versions/1.0.6/topics/powerSim), you need to indicate it, for example by including `library(simr)` in your code

Comment: The package is included. It runs and do simulation. It is just that when variables are set as factors it always shows predicted power as 0 with 0-3.62% CI.